# How to print a grid calender of 6 row by 7 column with users input in python

Tags: python-3.x

Hey everyone I need to write a program that asks the user for a month name and start day and then prints the calendar for that month in a 6 row by 7 column grid. (Ignoring issues of leap years, assume February has 28 days).

Output:

Enter the month('January', ...,'December'): November

Enter the start day ('Monday', ..., 'Sunday'): Sunday

```
November 
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su                    
                   1  
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 
23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
30
```

The output needs to always form a 6 row by 7 column grid. Spaces need to be used where necessary.

So I started like this:

```
month = input('Enter the month:',('January', ...,'December')) 
day = input('Enter the start day:',('Monday', ..., 'Sunday'))

print(month)
for leftmost in range(n,n+42,7):
    for value in range(leftmost,leftmost + 6):
        print("{0:2d} ".format(day), end=" ")
    print("{0:2d}".format(leftmost+6))
```

Python says I have a type error:

```
File "C:/Users/Nathan/Documents/printmonths.py", line 5, in <module>
     month = input('Enter the month:',('January', ...,'December'))
builtins.TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

and I don't really know how to continue the algorithm. 
Can anyone help me with this problem.

Comment: Can you show the error message you are getting?

Comment: re-edited the question

Comment: input() expects one string argument, while you gave it a pair of arguments, one of which is a tuple. I think you want to include (January, ..., December) in the string rather than provide it as a second argument.

Comment: yes, that's correct, but how do I include it in the string

Comment: `month = input('Enter the month: (\'January\', ..., \'December\')')`

Answer (score 0):

Utilize the fact that both `'` and `"` can delimit a Python string, e.g.:

```
month = input("Enter the month ('January', ...,'December'):")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count=0
p = int(input("Enter number of days in month:"))
q = int(input("Enter the starting day(0-6):"))
print("S  M   T   W  T  F  S")

print("    "*q,end="")
count=q

for i in range(1,p+1):
    count=count+1

    if count <= 7:
        if i<=9:
                print(i,end='  ')
        else:
                print(i,end=' ')
    else:
        count=0
        print("     ")
        if i<=9:
            print(i,end='  ')
        else:
            print(i,end=' ')
        count=count+1
print("")
```